# SQL Server : what's missing from the update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and trying to do an update statement and am unclear how to go about this. I can't even describe it properly enough to google it.

```
update S
set SlsTypId = 'Here'
from SVSLS S
join SVSLSOPS O on S.Slsid = O.SlsId
where O.SlsTypId = 'Here' 
  and O.SlsTypId <> 'OnOrder'
```

The trouble I am having is to make this update statement work when the slsid is distinct.

Here is some sample data:

```
SLSID   SLSTYPID    OPSID
-------------------------
R001005288  SI  1
R001005288  HERE    5
R001005288  OnOrder 8
R001005288  HERE    9
R001057955  BI  1
R001057955  BI  2
R001057955  BI  3
R001057955  BI  4
R001057955  BI  5
R001057955  HERE    6
R001105960  BR  1
R001105960  BR  2
R001107237  SR  1
R001107237  SR  2
R001107237  SR  3
R001107572  HERE    1
R001107572  OnOrder 2
R001107572  PDIS    3
R001107572  PDIS    4
R001107613  BR  1
R001107613  BR  2
R001107613  BR  3
R001107613  BR  4
R001107613  BR  5
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What version of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server) are you using, as the answer will be highly-dependent on this?

Comment: No need for this condition O.SlsTypId <> 'OnOrder'(as you already using O.SlsTypId = 'Here')

Comment: You listed 2 tables and provided information for 1 table only.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The other table in this case SVSLS has two columns slsid and slstypid (same as SVSLSOPS).  I omitted it because this was the part I was having difficulties with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Try this query by using wildcard to match And I think

`O.SlsTypId  LIKE '%OnOrder%'` will  not be necessary(sometimes) .Hope it helps you

```
 update S
 set SlsTypId = 'Here'
 from SVSLS S
 INNER join SVSLSOPS O on S.Slsid = O.SlsId
 WHERE O.SlsTypId  LIKE '%Here%'  
 AND O.SlsTypId  LIKE '%OnOrder%'
```

Comment: Hello.Thanks if it was really helpful for you please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: This is my first posting.  I've been looking around but don't see it.  Can you tell me how to mark this as a correct answer?